# querySelector inside of Table

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jquery-selectors

I have this simple chrome extension that allows the user to create a table however I can't bind the remove Button.

options.html

```
<body>
<!-- would be created as the user clicks on new Row -->
<table id="rows">
  <tr id="row0"> 
    <td>
      <input id="textBox" type="text">
      <button id="remove">Remove</button>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<!-- used as template -->
<table hidden>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="rowTemplate">
      <td>
        <input id="textBox" type="text">
        <button id="remove">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="newRow">new Row</button>
<script src="options.js"></script>
```

options.js

```
function Row() {
  var rows = document.getElementById('rows');
  this.node = document.getElementById('rowTemplate').cloneNode(true);
  this.node.id = 'row' + (Row.next_id++);
  this.node.row = this;
  rows.appendChild(this.node);
  this.node.hidden = false;

  var row = this;
  this.getElement('remove').onclick = function () {
    row.node.parentNode.removeChild(row.node);
  }
}

Row.next_id = 0;
Row.prototype.getElement = function (name) {
  return document.querySelector('#' + this.node.id + ' .' + name);
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('newRow').onclick = function() {
    new Row();
  };
}
```

The problem lies in the **querySelector** because whenever I click on 'new Row', I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null` pointing to the `getElement('remove').onclick` which calls `getElement()` where the querySelector returns null.

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same id in one document like those elements inside your `tr` template. Switch to classes.

Comment: You're trying to get the element that matches the selector which includes `'.remove'`, but you have nothing that includes the `class` `'remove'`. You probably intended to have the `id="remove"` in your template be `class="remove"`, which is needed as you need to not duplicate IDs within a document (also `id="textBox"`), both as wOxxOm mentioned. You appear to be trying to limit your `querySelector` to searching under the current element (`this.node`). Your should not be using `document.querySelector()` for this. Using `this.node.querySelector()` would be much more effective/appropriate.